# How to use functions and multiple arguments within case_when in dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, data-wrangling

For `ifelse` statements, its fairly easy to run multiple arguments with both functions and direct data manipulations like so:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Run Multiple Ifelse Statements ####
iris %>% 
  mutate(New.Sepal.Width = ifelse(Sepal.Width > 3.5,
                                  "Large",
                                  ifelse(Sepal.Width < 3,
                                         sqrt(Sepal.Width),
                                         NA)))
```

However I seem to not understand how to do the same with `case_when` in `dplyr`. If I run a similar code like this:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(New.Sepal.Width = case_when(
    Sepal.Width >= 3.5 ~ "Large",
    Sepal.Width <= 3 ~ "sqrt(Sepal.Width)",
    Sepal.Width > 3 | Sepal.Width < 3.5 ~ "NA"
  ))
```

It prints literally `sqrt(Sepal.Width)` rather than the square root. If I specify it as a normal function:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(New.Sepal.Width = case_when(
    Sepal.Width >= 3.5 ~ "Large",
    Sepal.Width <= 3 ~ sqrt(Sepal.Width), # change here
    Sepal.Width > 3 | Sepal.Width < 3.5 ~ "NA"
  ))
```

This ends up giving me other issues:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `New.Sepal.Width = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `case_when()`:

Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check `?case_when`, you can see that:

> The RHS does not need to be logical, but all RHSs must evaluate to
> the same type of vector.

So you need your RHS to be character only. You can do so by converting `sqrt(Sepal.Width)` to a character vector with `as.character` and replace `NA` with `NA_character_`.

You can do:

```r
iris %>% 
  mutate(New.Sepal.Width = case_when(
    Sepal.Width >= 3.5 ~ "Large",
    Sepal.Width <= 3 ~ as.character(sqrt(Sepal.Width)),
    Sepal.Width > 3 | Sepal.Width < 3.5 ~ NA_character_
  ))
```

---

Note that in `dplyr`'s [development version](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/main/NEWS.md), and supposedly from `dplyr 1.1` and onwards, `case_when` no longer requires `NA` to be specified beforehand, so this will work:

```r
iris %>% 
  mutate(New.Sepal.Width = case_when(
    Sepal.Width >= 3.5 ~ "Large",
    Sepal.Width <= 3 ~ as.character(sqrt(Sepal.Width)),
    Sepal.Width > 3 | Sepal.Width < 3.5 ~ NA
  ))
```

Comment: Thanks that works. By the way what is RHS in this context?

Comment: it means right-hand side. It's the part of the formula that is on the right of the `~`.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the extra info.